# ExtJS - Add values to FormPanel when it's fully loaded, including select stores

Tags: forms, extjs

In ExtJS modern 6.2, I want to set the FormPanel values using `form.setValues()`, but the stores of select fields are not loaded yet.

How can I execute the `form.setValues()` only when the form is 100% loaded?

Comment: Add an `onLoad` listener to call a custom method in your form. Have this custom method in the form verify if all the stores have been loaded and if yes, call `form.setValues()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormPanel has a "painted" event.  You could set the values from this event.

I don't generally use the setValues().  My data is stored in both Stores and Models.  Then I just bind the values in the form to the values in the Model.  Then when the form is ready it will display the values.  As the users edits the fields the data in the model is updated (two way binding).  Then after the form is validated you can call save on the model (or sync on a store).

Comment: How do you do the binding? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Here is a very good example of data binding (in this case grid to form) from a Sencha MVP
https://learnfromsaki.com/example-bind-grid-form/